# "List index out of range" error in For loop, where I tried defining the length through len() and appending

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to Python and I wanted to make a Hangman game to get a hang of the language.

```
print('You have 5 turns to guess the word.')
turn = int(5)
word = str('secret')
i = int(0)
time.sleep(1)
for i in range(len(word)):
    print('_', end='')
    time.sleep(0.3)
print()
time.sleep(1)
current = list()
while turn != 0:
    if turn > 1:
        print('You have', turn, 'guesses.')
    else:
        print('You have', turn, 'guess.')
    guess = input('Enter your guess.')
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            print(guess, end='')
            current[i] = guess
        else:
            print('_', end='')
            current[i] = '_'
    print(current)
    turn -= 1
```

In the above code, i'm getting a "List index out of range" error in the for loops. I thought the problem is that the list length is not defined at the start. So, I added this:

```
len(current) = len(word)
```

but, that didn't help.
Then I tried appending for the first turn:

```
        if j == 0:
            if guess == word[i]:
                print(guess, end='')
                current.append(guess)
            else:
                print('_', end='')
                current.append('_')
            j=1
        else:
            if guess != word[i]:
                print(current[i], end='')
            elif current[i] != '_':
                print(guess, end='')
                current[i] = word[i]
            else:
                print(guess, end='')
                current[i] = '_'
```

Even this wasn't working and now I'm lost.

Comment: And which line does throw the error ?

Comment: You need to set current to have the right number of elements: ‘current = [‘_’] * len(word)’

Comment: In place of `current = list()`, use `current = list(range(len(word))`

Comment: print(current[i], end='') this line is shown, but i think there's an error everywhere i used current[i]

Comment: @Srujan Your `current` list is of length 0. or say empty. So you can't access it using `current[i]` for any i.

Comment: `len(current) = len(word)` This doesn't increase the size of current list. `len(current` is just a temporary variable and assigning value `len(word)` to it has no effect on the size of `current` list.

Comment: current = [ ' _ ' ] * len(word) worked. Thanks guys

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh That's a syntax error, you can't assign to a function call in Python.

Comment: @Jasmijn Yes. Got that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not defined `current` as an empty list, because you can't be able to assign some letter at the specific index as they don't exists, do

```
current = ['_'] * len(word)
```

Then your `if/else` is wrong, as it assigns in `current` only the letter you just give, so you keep putting back `_` on thre previous letters found.

You may have only one `if` for good letters, to change the underscore, and just print the `current` after the `for` loop, don't need to do it twice (inside the loop)

```
current = ['_'] * len(word)
while turn != 0:
    if turn > 1:
        print('You have', turn, 'guesses left.')
    else:
        print('You have', turn, 'guess left.')
    guess = input('Enter your guess: ')
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            current[i] = guess
    print("".join(current))
    turn -= 1
```